# On the order of generating set elements??

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

My question is only for the abelian case, the following example is to clarify the idea in the non-abelian case

The dihedral group has the following presentation $$D_{2i}=\left<s,r/s^2=r^i=e,sr=r^{-1}s \right>$$
Order of $D_{2i}$ is $2i$ , if we take $S=\{s,r\}$ and $H=\{s,sr\}$, then  $D_{2i}=\left<S \right>=\left<H\right>$, but sum order of element of $S$ is 2+i and of $H$ is 4. From this we deduce that there is no relation between the order of the non-abelian group and the orders of elements in minimal generating set.

My question is there any relation between the order of **abelian** group and the order of elements in its minimal generating sets?

I guess the following is true $S=\{s_1,\ldots,s_k\}$ is a minimal generating set of abelian group $G$ then $\Pi_{i=1}^k order(s_i) \geq order(G)$.

```
Is this equation is true, and is there any other relations?
```

Please, any idea will be useful.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88106/minimal-generation-for-finite-abelian-groups and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572419/orders-of-elements-in-minimal-generating-sets-of-abelian-p-groups.

Comment: refer your own question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481178/oder-of-elements-of-the-generating-set